# Polymer CSS - Forcing a Width of 0

Tags: css, polymer

I'm working on a Polymer app. I keep running into oddities. At this time, I'm trying to put a [paper item](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-item) in my app. At runtime, these elements appear to add an HTML element that looks like this:

```
<div id="contentIcon" class="content-icon style-scope paper-icon-item">
</div>
```

For some reason, this element is always 56px in width. In the Chrome Developer tools, I can see `width:56px`. If I set it to `width:0px` in the Chrome Dev tools, the UI looks how I want. In an attempt to do this, I added the following to my CSS:

```
.content-icon.paper-icon-item {
  width:0px !important;
}
```

However, the 56px width still remains. I do not understand why at I have to do to remove this 56px width.

Thanks,

Comment: you need to make your css more specific than the one from Polymer

Comment: Seems weird to have a zero width... Maybe `overfow: hidden`?

Comment: Have you tried using a `/deep/` selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using a class attribute for defining a web component?
That syntax seems quite weird.
Can you please provide with more specific description regarding this issue as it doesn't seems clear.
AFAIK, the correct syntax for including a paper-item component in your code should be:

```
<paper-item>
  <paper-item-body two-line>
    <div>Show your status</div>
    <div secondary>Your status is visible to everyone</div>
  </paper-item-body>
  <iron-icon icon="warning"></iron-icon>
</paper-item>
```